# How to create relationship for Pplymorphic association

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have 3 different tables and one of which is the polymorphic table.

```
CREATE TABLE pictures
(
id serial
imageable_type text not null
imageable_id integer not null
comment on table pictures is 'imageable_id belongs to users_id and products_id';
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
id serial
name string
);

CREATE TABLE products
(
id serial
name string
);
```

`
This is how the structure will look like.

The Picture table is related to users table and the products table through **imageable_id** column.

How can I query like this in hausra if it is **Rails-style**(Withouht any reference to FK)

```
{
     products {
         name
         pictures {
              id
              name
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to associate the records in each model like this:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Then you can query the pictures from your object like:

> @product.pictures
> or
> @user.pictures

In graphql you can then create PictureType and include all the fields of the picture. then you can create a ProductType to get the attached images to a product like this:

```
class Types::ProductType < Types::BaseObject
  field :pictures, [Types::PictureType], null: false

  def pictures
    object.pictures
  end
end
```

And get the pictures for a product like in your query...

```
query {
  products {
    id
    name
    pictures {
      id
      url
    }
  }
}
```

For reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations